# Cypress drag and drop a 'react sortable tree' element

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, cypress

I'm trying to use Cypress to drag and drop an element from the "react sortable tree" library
https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree#troubleshooting

However, the usual way of doing this is not working. Things I've tried:

```
    cy.get(subject).trigger("mousedown", { which: 1, force: true })
                .trigger("mousemove", { pageX: xPos, pageY: yPos, force: true })
                .trigger("mouseup", { force: true })
```

OR

```
    cy.get(subject).trigger("mousedown", { button: 0, force: true })
    cy.get(target).trigger("mousemove")
              .trigger("mouseup")
```

Has anybody successfully tested drag and drop using Cypress on react sortable tree?

Comment: Follow-up question: How do I then drop the element over the target with a slight offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    cy.get(subject).trigger("dragstart")
    cy.get(target).trigger("drop")
              .trigger("dragend")
```

the above worked for me